# Find Laplace Transform using unit step function and t-shifting. (5.3-35, 5.3-36)

Tags: laplace-transform

How do the Laplace Transforms vary between the two following functions? What I am really asking is if I calculated the following Laplace Transform correctly...

$$\mathcal{L}\{(t-1)u(t-1)\}=\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}$$

...what should the Laplace Transform be for this function:

$$\mathcal{L}\{(t)u(t-1)\}=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one sided Laplace transform is defined as
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt
$$ 
and the Unit step function is defined as 
$$
\mathcal{U}(t)=
\begin{cases}
1, & t>0\\
0, & t<0
\end{cases}
$$
so the 
$$
\mathcal{L}\{t\mathcal{U}(t-1)\} = \int_0^{\infty}t\mathcal{U}(t-1)e^{-st}dt =
\int_1^{\infty}te^{-st}dt = \mbox{???}
$$

Comment: Thank you for responding but I do not understand the answer. If I solve for the integral given will I get the Laplace for the second unshifted t function

Comment: I edited my comment. Please have a second look at it.

Comment: @JulesManson if you solve the integral given, you will still need to solve $\mathcal{L}\{-\mathcal{U}(t-1)\}$ since $\mathcal{L}\{(t-1)\mathcal{U}(t-1)\} = \mathcal{L}\{t\mathcal{U}(t-1)\}-\mathcal{L}\{\mathcal{U}(t-1)\}$

Comment: Thank you so much. That is what I needed. Do you mind if I ask. Are you a math teacher or an engineer?

Comment: I think it is wonderful that you are pursuing your PhD. I am currently working really hard on my BSME by attaining a minimum 3.0 GPA because I wish to pursue an MS afterwards. And who knows if I have the "right stuff" after all and if I am smarter than I give myself credit for and if the gods up there smile on me perhaps I may also attempt a PhD one day.

Comment: @JulesManson I have to get accepted to a school first. I will find out in March-April.

Comment: is this how to tag your user name to another posted question? Anyway I do not trust the answer I got on another question I posted and I would love for you to look at it. Here it is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131483/find-laplace-transform-using-unit-step-function-and-t-shifting-5-3-38