# Find Laplace Transform using unit step function and t-shifting. (5.3-38)

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification

Please check my work. Did I calculate the following Laplace Transform correctly?

$$\mathcal{L}\{t^2u(t-1)\}=\mathcal{L}\{(t-1)^2u(t-1)\}+\mathcal{L}\{u(t-1)\}$$

$$=\frac{2e^{-s}}{s^3}+\frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect. It is easier to resort to definition of the Laplace transform. $$\int_0^{\infty} t^2\mathcal{U}(t-1)e^{-st}dt = \int_1^{\infty} t^2e^{-st}dt$$
Note that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}e^{-st} = t^2e^{-st}$. 
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\int_1^{\infty} e^{-st}dt = \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\frac{e^{-s}}{s} = \frac{2 e^{-s}}{s^3}+\frac{2 e^{-s}}{s^2}+\frac{e^{-s}}{s}
$$

Comment: Thank you again for spending more time on my posts. I guess the definition is easier in some cases but that is only because the unit step function is trickier than it appears. I feel like if I can't get past this I may not do well in my studies. I guess I have to try harder.

Comment: can you show me how this should have been done with unit step function? That is the very short anemic section in the chapter on how to use the unit step function that I am on now. I think text books on differential equations really need to expand on this topic to give it more clarity.

Comment: @JulesManson this is how you do it with the step function. Look at the bounds of integration. The step function shifted the lower bound from 0 to 1 since it was u(t-1)

Answer (score 0):

Replace $t$ with $t + 1$ and you can see the answer is no:

$$\mathcal{L}\{(t+1)^2u(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{t^2 u(t)\} + 2t\mathcal{L}\{u(t)\} + \mathcal{L}\{u(t)\} \neq \mathcal{L}\{t^2u(t)\}+\mathcal{L}\{u(t)\}$$

Comment: What should my solution look like? I need more guidance.

Comment: @dustin would you look at this for me.